# I'm unable to boot my Windows USB drive on my Mac. How do I do fix this?

Tags: windows, boot, mac, usb, cpu

I'm new to this community, but I've been into computers for a while.

Lately, I've been trying to create a bootable USB drive with Windows installed on it that I can plug into and boot on my MacBook Pro. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IhW722IMwE&t=1111s) tutorial to the word, right up the part where he modifies the boot security settings to permit booting from external sources. My Mac is old enough that it doesn't have a T2 chip, and therefore does not have this setting.

When I turn on the computer and choose to boot from my external drive, I am greeted by the [Windows 10 boot screen](https://neosmart.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/Boot-screen.png). It will try to load for about 30 seconds before I am presented with a blue screen error, which displays either error code 0xc0000001 or stop code "MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION".

When I boot back into my Mac's drive, everything is fine and there is a popup that says "Your computer was restarted because of a problem." If I go to the details, it has a CPU error log that I don't know how to read. You can read it [here](https://pastebin.com/RiwNyrre). To be clear, the Mac is totally fine and functional. It just displays the popup along with the log.

Based on all of this, what I'm guessing is that when Windows tries to boot, it thinks there's something wrong with my CPU and aborts the process. However, I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue further.

Any ideas?

Relevant Details:

- Computer: 13" 2016 Macbook Pro
- Primary OS: macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
- Processor: Dual-Core Intel Core i5
- External Drive: Lacie 5TB Rugged

EDIT: Just tried to reset NVRAM, which didn't help.

EDIT 2: I tried it again after disabling system integrity protection. Didn't help.

EDIT 3: I ran a diagnostic on the external drive, and I got this: [image: this] I think I may have found the problem, but I still don't know how to fix it.

EDIT 4: I believe have finally found the problem. After trying @DavidAnderson's suggestion, I decided to try to boot my drive on another MacBook Pro, and it worked (until I get a "SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED" error, but that is, I think, because I need different drivers for that Mac). This means that the problem is specific to my computer.

Comment: For those of us who hate watching tutorial videos, the same instructions are in text - https://9to5mac.com/2020/07/14/install-windows-mac-external-ssd-drive-boot-camp-2020-video/

Comment: Have you tried boot camp?

Comment: @bobsfriend I don't have enough extra space on my internal drive for a Windows partition, which is why I'm trying to use an external drive. Boot Camp won't work on external drives.

Comment: I am amazed that your video and Tetsujin's reference are both less than a year old. Using third party tools (such as WinsToUSB and VmWare Fusion) to install Windows 10 on your Mac is no longer necessary regardless of whether you install on an internal or external drive.

Comment: @DavidAnderson If you know of a better method for installing Windows on an external drive, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I can refer you to [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/drivers-not-working-on-windows-10-installed-cli-process-on-external-ssd-runnin/384447#384447). You will also find a link to other answers that may involve third party tools.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I followed your steps closely, and when I booted on the Windows installer I got stop code "WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR". Any ideas?

Comment: A 5 TB drive might to to big to boot the installer from. You could try coping the files to a flash drive. Also, if you have a `AutoUnattend.xml` file in the root folder, you could try renaming or deleting the file.